# SAP SAVE_TEXT function module is that secure against SQL Injection?

Tags: abap

I have question regarding [abap](/questions/tagged/abap) function module **SAVE_TEXT**. I assume that it is possible to create custom `tdobject` and `tdid`, then the longtextes are to be stored in the tables `STXH, STX`L. How secure is the **SAVE_TEXT** against `SQL` injection attacks? Is it not vulnerable because of encoding the textes in RAW format?

Answer (score 2):

Your first assumption was either lost in translation or wrong in the first place - the valid values of `TDOBJECT` and `TDID` are maintained manually using the transaction `SE75`, usually by the application developer. They are not created as part of the everyday application processing.

As far as the database access is concerned, there are two security levels to protect against SQL injection, although one was not designed to be a security level:

1. The contents of the text are stored in an internal form that is serialized as a byte string. Whatever SQL commands might have been present in the original text do not make it through this conversion.
2. The DML commands are passed through the usual database interface layer that uses prepared statements with a fixed set of variables that are supplied with values only when executing the statements. As far as I can see, no dynamic SQL statements are used to modify `STX*` texts.

For normal business applications, this should be safe enough. If you want to run a nuclear power plant, well - we would have to talk.

Comment: To add, if you are worried about SQL injection because you are running a nuclear power plant, then I would not start of with securing 'SAVE_TEXT'.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation, VWegert! It is very useful. Surely I wan't run a nuclear power plant. With custom tdobject and tdid i meant creation of text objects with SPRO transaction :-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tomdemuyt: Just wanted to illustrate that "security" is not a simple thing. Cheap, usable, secure - choose two. You can't have all three at once - ever.

Comment: @Elena: Citing SPRO as a transaction is about as useful as citing SMEN  - that is, not useful at all. There are tens of thousands of transactions and other settings that are accessible from SPRO. Always use the "real" transaction, view or view cluster name, BAdI definition, Enhancement Spot or what ever you're referring to.